# Web content not displayed after adding new WFE to SP2013 Farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-application, sharepoint-farm

I wanted to replace WFE and first added new server to existing SP2013 Farm.
I could add farm to new server however, when I open site after shutdown old WFE, it returns 404, 505, etc.
Confirmed that services could run in Configuration Wizards and I have no idea what to do next.

This is my first time to create SP server so I truly require your help.
It is so much appreciated to your help!

Comment: You might wanna check your DNS. Probably points to the old web server. Or if you had multiple WFE and uses a loadbalancer, the new server needs to be added to that cluster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice.
There is no loadbalancer in the farm so I will try to ask our IT team to check configuration of DNS server first.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS Manager and check your application pools whether are all running. If not, start your application pools. To see if they are running click on Application Pool folder and you should see the list on the right-side under state should be "running" or "stopped". Also check the identity of your application pools whether are using farm account.